# Pandas read_json() fails with a simple JSON string

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a `DataFrame` object from a json string (not a file):

```
json_string = "[{'code': '8', 'name': 'Human'}, {'code': '11', 'name': 'Orc'}]"
df = pd.read_json(json_string)
```

but this approach causes the following error:

```
ValueError: Expected object or value
```

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) makes it sound like this would be possible:

> pandas.**read_json**(*path_or_buf=None, orient=None, typ='frame', dtype=True, convert_axes=True, convert_dates=True, keep_default_dates=True, numpy=False, precise_float=False, date_unit=None, encoding=None, lines=False, chunksize=None, compression='infer'*)
>
> Convert a JSON string to pandas object
>
> - **path_or_buf** : a valid JSON string or file-like, default: *None*
>     The string could be a URL. Valid URL schemes include http, ftp, s3, and file. For file URLs, a host is expected. For instance, a local file could be file://localhost/path/to/table.json

I've already tried calling the method with several combinations of `orient` and none succeeded. Any tips on how to accomplish this?

I really don't want the overhead of saving my string to a file to be able to use `read_json()` successfully.

Comment: JSON object `keys` and `values` should be enclosed with double quotes not single.

Comment: I know and if I could change that, I would. But in this case is *no-can't-do*.

Comment: Then use `eval` to convert it to `list` of `dict`

Comment: @karlphillip, if you can't change the quotation marks, could you at least add a preprocessing line before reading the json? `json_string = json_string.replace('\'', '\"')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to evaluate the string to dict and then pass directly to `DataFrame` constructor.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame(eval("[{'code': '8', 'name': 'Human'}, {'code': '11', 'name': 'Orc'}]"))

    code   name
0   8      Human
1   11     Orc
```

Similarly you can also use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) in place of `eval`

```
>>> import ast
>>> pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval("[{'code': '8', 'name': 'Human'}, {'code': '11', 'name': 'Orc'}]"))

    code   name
0   8      Human
1   11     Orc
```

Comment: Compare `eval('print("delete root")')` to `ast.literal_eval('print("delete root")')`. I would stick with the second option.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that OP is parsing a Python object and not a JSON object, so `read_json` is not appropriate.

If one is actually ingesting Python structs, then `eval` is appropriate.

The `eval` method will not work if you have JSON booleans, because Python does not parse `true` or `false` as `True/False`.

Also, your `json_string` is not [valid JSON](https://www.json.org).  Single quotes are not delimiters in JSON.  So you must also change that (the comments indicate this).

If one did need to have `pandas.read_json` process a valid JSON string, then per the [Pandas GitHub issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/52271) that caused this to break, you should wrap `json_string` in a `StringIO` so that it may be read akin to a file.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

json_string = '[{"code": "8", "name": "Human"}, {"code": "11", "name": "Orc"}]'
df = pd.read_json(StringIO(json_string))
```